# owl-stage width on mobile (or small devices) view is larger than screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

I'm working on a clients website, implementing owl-carousel, but when going into mobile view in chrome + Firefox, owl-stage width (Which is auto calculated) goes crazy as I resize and go back go normal, widths around 4000px...etc.

P.S. code works fine on normal desktop view, it all goes crazy on 576px and below.

I have googled owl-stage width issue and found many old reports and solutions (including stack-overflow) that did not fix my problem, including setting overflow, removing owl options to debug.

code can be found here:
https://www.fisique.co/v2/

owl-stage width should be normal and not more than screen, which in return will render the h1 above it to be perfectly centered on the screen.

Comment: Problem seems to be related to another JS library i'm using (**pagepilling.js**), somehow related to parent divs set as table and table-cell. Will play around and see.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I spent more than 12 hours to figure out why this weird behavior.
Turns out, if you're using **PagePilling.js** (or **fullPage.js**) and trying to mix with **Owl.Carousel** or any other Carousel plugin, a conflict occurs because of css display property of auto generated divs set to `table`

The solution for my case was adding `table-layout: fixed`:

```
.pp-section.pp-table {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
}
```

If you're interested to read more about it:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/895